# call function with arguments via instance.cmd()

Tags: python

my problem might be very easy for some experienced python programmers (I'm not one of them).

I'm trying to start a server with an argument.

Currently i'm doing:

```
def startServer(host):
    host.cmd( 'python server.py &' )
```

Is there a way to pass an argument to **server.py**?

Comment: What arguments do you want to use? Also, what is `host` going to be?

Comment: host is a node in the "Mininet" it's a virtual network... maybe cmd is a parameter from that class. I thought it could might be something in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def startServer(host):
    host.cmd( 'python server.py an_argument_to_server &' )
```

is that really what you are looking for?

Comment: I need to try whether it works for me but it looks exactly like what i'm looking for. As I said.. it might be very easy for someone who knows about python

Comment: Works! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

In order to run `python run server.py` from the command line, we can use the `subprocess` module. Documentation can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html.

```
import subprocess

def startServer(host, argument):
    subprocess.call(['python', 'server.py', argument])
```

When you call the `startServer` function with some argument (say `an_argument_to_server`), it will run `python server.py an_argument_to_server` in command line. We don't need the `&` character, as `subprocess` will automatically run in the background. The `subprocess` module also works for python 3.x

Comment: Im pretty sure OP is using a ssh library ... where host is an ssh instance that targets a remote shell +1 all the same ... but if you are gonna use subprocess you should really pass it like `["cmd","arg1","arg2"]` and you dont really need the '&' since it will run in parallel automatically with subprocess